# Apex batch class :System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: batch

any Idea how to fix this Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual code its difficult to say where the issue is there in your code but in a generic way what this error means is

you cannot do a DML and then try to do a callout. you need to split them into seperate transactions by doing the callout in a future method or queueables.

In your batch class execute methods code check the sequence of your code and make changes accordingly